# dynamic_mapping.template_meta_types.mapping.path is invalid in ElasticSearch 8

Tags: elasticsearch

We have recently update to ElasticSearch 8 and since we can see following errors:

> dynamic template [template_meta_types] has invalid content,
> attempted to validate it with the following match_mapping_type: `[object, string, long, double, boolean, date, binary]`, last error: `[Unknown mapping attributes [{path=full}]`.

The relevant portion of the mapping is:

```json
        {
          "template_meta_types" : {
            "path_match" : "meta.*",
            "mapping" : {
              "path" : "full",
              "properties" : {
                "date" : {
                  "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
                  "type" : "date"
                },
              },
              {…},
              "type" : "object"
            }
          }
        }
```

As I took over managing the ES server, I am not entirely sure the reason for this as this field seems to be either deprecated or removed.

What is the correct solution for this? Should I completely remove this field? What would be the correct way?

Comment: Which version did you upgrade from?

Comment: From 7 to 8, but the mapping remained unchanged since even earlier versions.

Comment: The `"path": "full"` setting is weird at this location and doesn't seem valid

Comment: So what would be the easiest way of removing it?

Comment: When do you get the error? Can you share the full log?

Comment: I get the error when I import production snapshot to development elastic. Basically this is full log. There is just the error mentioned in the question.